# Odoo - Make a field invisible for 1 group

Tags: odoo

I want to make a control invisible for users of only 1 group. All users of other groups have the right to access this field.
I know how to do the opposite, that is to say, restrict access to the field to 1 group. But this way the list will be very long if I have to put all the groups. Is there a simple method, preferably with Odoo Studio?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can precede the group's external ID by `!`, for example:

```
groups="!website.group_multi_website"
```

The [user_has_groups](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L1204) method (which is used to apply the [groups](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L849)) will return `True` if the current user is a member of one of the given groups not preceded by `!` and is not member of any of the groups preceded by `!`